# mootools ie8 array.append error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, mootools

Im trying to fix some old mootools script, in Internet Explorer  9, Firefox Array.append works just fine

```
ar ewls = document.getElements('a');
var lol = [];
lol.append(ewls);
```

But in  IE8 im geting this error in the console 
"SCRIPT5028: Function.prototype.apply: oczekiwano obiektu tablicy lub argumentów" (expected array or arguments)

http://jsfiddle.net/dKkX5/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

er. `Array.append`? `lol = []; lol.push(ewls);`

you ought to consider a collection. you have a data type mismatch. merging a collection with a static array won't work. `var lol = new Elements();` - it's like an array only with element protos as well. then `lol.append(ewels);`

http://jsfiddle.net/dKkX5/5/

```
var ewls = document.getElements('a');
var lol = new Elements();

lol.append(ewls);
lol.length; // 5
```

keep in mind the append is from 1.3+ - in 1.2 it was `Array.extend`

Comment: thanks  but using Elements() instead of an array breaks the script so it stops working in Fx and IE9

Comment: that's fine - so just do array.include if you need unique members or else, .push.

Comment: see updated fiddle. it works in fx and ie9 on the fiddle for certain. if you have issues with it within your script, you need to fix them separately - as this part is correct.

Comment: thanks, maybe i was too tired but when i tried it today it worked :)